# zmq: can multiple threads PUSH in a simple PUSH-PULL pattern

Tags: multithreading, sockets, thread-safety, zeromq, simplex

I have two processes: a **producer** which pushes messages via [ZMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) to a **consumer** in a simple PULL-PUSH point-to-point pattern. The producer has several internal threads that `send()` via zmq. However, 0MQ's docs *suggest not to share sockets between threads*.

**Must I use a single thread to send?**
Assuming there is no strict requirement for keeping the sending order between the threads, doesn't the fact that the socket is a one-directional simplex allow multiple threads to use it without introducing locks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to create a separate PUSH socket on each of producer's threads and `connect` all these sockets to a single PULL socket in consumer.

It's explicitly stated in the guide that ZeroMQ sockets must be used on a single thread. I'd say that violating this requirement is not a good idea, even if it seems to work: things may break in the next version of the library or on some specific platform or in some specific load scenario. So, it's just too risky.